# Why not delete the node, itself?

Tags: nodes

I am a real rookie here and am taking data structures class in C++! The above question was possed when talking ablout working with lists and nodes. One of the design questions is for a deletion will we delete the node, itself, or the node after the location at which we popint? The last question seemed a little stupid in my mind and I was told "The answer is obvious to anyone who has ever actually tried to write the code, which is a good argument for not just reading computer programs without implementing the concepts on your own."

But Never Given the obvious answer...? Can anybody please elaberate to me the reason for not deleting the NODE, itself?

Comment: If you deleted the node itself,you will lose track of the list

Answer (score 0):

If you delete the node that you are pointing to, then where would you be?

Comment: Thanks Everybody I was just reading up on linked lists and found exactly why we cannot do that or shouldn't do that for the obvious reasons that I now see. But if I am using double linked lists I don't have to worry about the above situation. Correct?.

Comment: Usually, for doubly linked lists, you:
1) get a pointer to the node to be deleted.
2) Update the forward and backward pointers to remove the node from the list.
3) Using the pointer from #1, delete the node.